# Linux: zip greater than 4Gb

Tags: linux, zip

I'm getting an error when I try and zip a large file on Linux because it is too large for zip to deal with. Anyone know what commands I can use to get around this?

This is the error I'm getting:

> zip error: Entry too big to split, read, or write (file exceeds Zip's 4GB uncompressed size limit)

It is a simple text file, log file in fact.

Comment: use tar+gzip instead.

Comment: Just split the file into 1GiB chunks and zip those. Or use a modern compression algorithm, you don't need an archive format in your case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the linux split command to chop your log file into smaller files.

and consider setting up log rotate so this doesn't happen again.

Comment: Just adding this to support others users if they search for this. I used this command to split the file into 1Gb slices: split -b 1024m access_log2 access_log_

Answer (score 16):

The basic Zip format has a limit of 4 GB per file. You need to upgrade your `zip` tool to one that supports Zip64:

```
$ zip -v
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
This is Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.
...

Zip special compilation options:
        ...
        ZIP64_SUPPORT        (use Zip64 to store large files in archives)
```

Alternatively, use a different archive format such as 7z or *tar*.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine all parts together.

Multi-part  archives  are  not  yet supported (unzip v.6.0), except in conjunction with zip. All parts must be concatenated together.
zip 3.0 and later can combine multi-part (split)  archives  into  a  combined  single-file archive  using

```
zip  -s- inarchive.zip -O outarchive.zip
```

Comment: Is that `zip  -s-` correct?